# How to reinitialize a layer in Keras but not the weights

Tags: keras

I want to copy some layers of a given model in an other new model (with all their attributes like stride, padding etc.). I want to keep the weights and attributes but not the inbound_node/outbound_node property linked to the old model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any function in Keras to do that but it's very easy with the `get_config`, `get_weights()` and `set_weights()` method of Keras Layers.

```py
    new_fresh_layer = layer.__class__(**layer.get_config())
    old_layer_weights = layer.get_weights()
    x = new_fresh_layer(layer_inputs)
    new_fresh_layer.set_weights(old_layer_weights)
```

if also works when adding layers sequentialy to a model:

```py
    model1 = Sequential()
    old_layer =  Dense(10, input_shape=(10,))
    model1.add(old_layer)

    model2 = Sequential()
    new_layer = old_layer.__class__(**old_layer.get_config())
    model2.add(new_layer)
    new_layer.set_weights(old_layer.get_weights())

    assert (new_layer.get_weights()[0] == old_layer.get_weights()[0]).all()
    assert (new_layer.get_weights()[1] == old_layer.get_weights()[1]).all()
```